# Check/compare a method from any instance of a class

Tags: java, coordinates, instance, distance

I have two classes, `BasicEnemy.java` and `Upgrade.java`. I have a getX() method in each, which return the X coordinate of an instance of the class.

From *Upgrade.java*, I want to be able to check if the X coordinate of any instance of BasicEnemy is near the X coordinate of any instance of Upgrade. Currently, I have a line of code that does not work:

```
if(main.distance(getX(), getY(), BasicEnemy.getX(), BasicEnemy.getY()) < 15)
```

(The `main.distance` method consumes two sets of (X,Y) coordinates and outputs the distance between them.)

How can I check if any instance of Upgrade is close to any instance of BasicEnemy? Thanks

Comment: it seems you need a third class responsible for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to loop over all basic enemies, and all upgrades to see if the distance between any pair is less than what you consider "close."

This can be improved by using fancy algorithms.  Try searching using the keyword `spacial partitioning` if you're feeling academic.

If you post the code in `distance` I'd be happy to fix it for you. Without seeing it, if you're sure the distance calculation is correct, check that the coordinates used for enemy and upgrade are in the same coordinate space (ie. both are world coordinates)

EDIT:

Based on your comments, you're confused about what static means. A static variable is shared across every instance a class.  In this case, your enemies should surely not have a static `getX()` routine.  Every enemy needs his own position, they do not share a singular position.

So I suggest:

1. Make your upgrade and enemy classes have non-static x and y variables, and non-static get/set routines.
2. Store all your enemy instances in a data structure, such as a list.
3. Store all your upgrade instances in a data structure, such as a list.

Then enumerate over both like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<enemies.size();i++){
    Enemy enemy = enemies.get(i);
    for(int j=0;j<upgrades.size();j++){
        Upgrade upgrade = upgrades.get(j);
        if(main.distance(enemy.getX(),upgrade.getX(),enemy.getY(),upgrade.getY())<15){
            //enemy is close to upgrade.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code for distance is:
    double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        return Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    }
However, that is not the problem. The problem is trying to reference BasicEnemy.getX() from a non-static context, because BasicEnemy.getX() is static. I need something that would do this:
    if(main.distance(getX(), getY(), [everyInstanceOfBasicEnemy].getX(), [everyInstanceOfBasicEnemy].getY())

Comment: Sorry... I hit the enter key too early. My response is above.

Comment: That's fine, Your calculation looks correct.  I've edited my question based on your comments about static context.

Comment: Awesome! With just a few modifications, I got your code working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a `Mediator` , a class that can send message to Upgrade instance and BasicEnemy instances, but for that you have to make them collegues so create a common interface like .

```
public interface Targetable{

int getX();

}
```

now in your class

`public BasicEnemy implements Targetable`
`public Upgrade implements Targetable`

and a Mediator class

```
  public  class TargetMediator  {
    Set<Upgrade> upgradeables;


    public Targeteable isSomeOneCloseToMe (Targeteable basicEnemy){
                //code here
    }

    }
```

You may want read about this design-pattern : [Mediator](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html)

Comment: I do already have an interface, Entity, that has the getX() method, and both BasicEnemy and Upgrade implement it. Would I just use that in place of 'Targetable'?

Comment: @user2562011 yeah you got it right you may want read about `Mediator` pattern it seems that is what you are looking for!!